# I am having trouble changing the color of a chart series under certain conditions

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I apologize for the vagueness of the question above but I don't really know how else to ask this.

I am using the FormatPercent() function to store well... a percent value in a variable.  Depending on what that value is I change the color of a series in a chart that I have.  This works great for the most part provided the value of "percent" doesn't exceed 100%.

Code that sets the value of variable "percent":

```
If Not dt.Rows(0)("Actual").ToString = "" And Not dt.Rows(0)("Projected").ToString = "" Then
                    percent = FormatPercent(actual / projected)
                Else
                    percent = "No Data"
                End If
```

For example I have tried:

```
If percent < "26" Then
                    itdChart.Series(0).Color = Color.Red
                ElseIf percent < "90" And percent >= "26" Then
                    itdChart.Series(0).Color = Color.Yellow
                ElseIf percent >= "90" Then
                    itdChart.Series(0).Color = Color.Green
                End If
```

this is pretty self explanatory, if the value is between 0 and 25% then the color is red, between 26% and 90% its yellow and above 90% its green.

This works great for the most part, the problem arises when the percent value exceeds 100%. In the event that "percent" exceeds 100 the color for the series is set to red instead of remaining green.  This if statement is the only place in my code where I am setting the color for the series and I am not quite sure that when I have a value of say 117% it displays red.

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The problem is in comparing the *string* "26" to another string, say "120", and forgetting that "1" sorts *before* "2". You probably want something like `If percent <> "No Data" AndAlso CDbl(percent) < 26 Then`... so that it uses numbers for the comparison.

Comment: Unfortunately the issue with CDbl() is that it does exactly that, it converts the whole percent into a decimal making my 117% 1.17.  In the end I can always redo the numbers to be 'If CDbl(percent) < .26 Then', But I was curious if there was a way to do it with whole numbers

Comment: Is there any reason to use a string for the value? Could you leave the ratio as a number and only convert it to a string when it comes to using it for display?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, no, no reason other than an oversight on my part.  I have a terrible habit of using string values more than I probably should.

Comment: I see a little bit of code re-writing in your near future... ;)

Comment: Store the percentage as a number  eg Dim percent as Double = actual / projected.  Then format that for display.  Makes numeric Comparisions much simpler and reliable.

Comment: Did you find the issue on the question you just deleted?

Comment: @DaleK, yes I did. The question had been closed, I wasn't sure if I should remove it or not and went with the former.  The error was popping when I was trying to store the "CreateDate" string value in a label I had on my page.  The data type was DateTime and when I tried formatting as .ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") it would throw the exception. After removing the "MM-dd-yyyy" it works.  As to why this is exactly, I'm not too sure.

Comment: Given a lot of people put in a lot of time to help you, you could have at least commented that you found the issue and then waited a day to delete.